# jQuery animate on an image replacement

Tags: jquery, image, animation

Hope you can advise I would like to add some simple fade in out of an image replacement which I have hooked into a select menu.ie,

```
$("#vehicle").change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $("#selectedVehicle").attr('src', '/assets/images/mini/'+selected+'.png');
});

<img id="selectedVehicle" src="/assets/v2/images/select-vehicle.png">
```

any suggestions how I can do it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This will work best if you preload the images.

```
$("#vehicle").change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var image = $("#selectedVehicle");
    image.fadeOut('fast', function () {
        image.attr('src', '/assets/images/mini/'+selected+'.png');
        image.fadeIn('fast');
    });
});
```

This will fade the image out, change the `src`, then fade it back in. Reference the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) for more information on the fading functions.

Again, you should preload your images, otherwise it might fade back while still loading.

Comment: Would it be a meaningful thing to do if I sandwiched an animated loading gif fadeIn/fadeOut in between img fadeIn/fadeOut so that I don't preload the images, and fadeIn the image when it is fully loaded?

Answer (score 4):

I've gone for preloading the image on page load, rather than on the fly...:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function buildUrl(val) {
    return '/assets/images/mini/' + val + '.png';
  };

  $('#vehicle').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $('#selectedVehicle').fadeOut('fast', function () {
      $(this).attr('src', buildUrl(value)).fadeIn('fast');
    });
  }).children('option').each(function () {
    var img = document.createElement("img");

    img.src = buildUrl($(this).val());
    img.onload = function () {};
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Example with "load" event:

```
$("#vehicle").on('change', function(){
  var selected = $(this).val();
  var image = $("#selectedVehicle");
  image.fadeOut('fast', function () {
     image.attr('src', '/assets/images/mini/'+selected+'.png');
  });
  image.one("load",function(){
    image.fadeIn('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: ```image.on("load",function(){
    image.fadeIn('fast');
  });```

Comment: Krishna Karki, can you comment why using `.on` is better?

Comment: I think that she thought is was a typo when in fact it is not.... `https://api.jquery.com/one/`