# Adding duration animation to jQuery hover effect using .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have 3 images that I am creating an effect for, where when hovered on, the image swaps to a different image. When trying to add a duration to the transition using the .animate() method, the entire effect is disabled. Is there a better method than using .animate(), or is there an issue in my code that stops .animate() from working?

Cheers

HTML

```
<img class="navbarimg" data-alt-src="images/icons/facebookhover.png" src="images/icons/facebook.png" alt="Facebook Page">
<img class="navbarimg"  data-alt-src="images/icons/instagramhover.png" src="images/icons/instagram.png" alt="Instagram Page">
<img class="navbarimg"  data-alt-src="images/icons/githubhover.png" src="images/icons/github.png" alt="Github Page">
```

jQuery

```
/* Hover effect for the nav bar */
/* Section A - Function to make the alt src be used instead of the default source */
    var sourceSwap = function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
        $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
        $this.attr('src', newSource);
    }

/* Section B - Runs the function to switch the src's */
    $(function () {
        /* Finds images wiht the 'navbarimg' class, and runs the function for those images */
        $('img.navbarimg').hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that, what kind of animation are you looking at? you can have something with opacity

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744579/jquery-animate-on-an-image-replacement

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute

Comment: I'll try explain it better, but basically, when the user hovers over the image, the first image transitions into the second image over a period of time.

Comment: Found an answer for this question here: 
   
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314405/animating-src-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

As you asked for better alternative you could use fontawesome or just include these 3 icons in your custom font if your images are not different from regular social media icons.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
.fa{ font-size: 40px; margin: 10px; cursor:pointer;
  transition: color .3s ease-out;
}
.fa:hover { color: skyblue;}  
</style>


<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>

<br>
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-github-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer, but I've developed my own icons for use on my site, so I doubt I can use this method, but I will look into it, cheers.